# LibGDX TiledMap Rendering

Tags: java, libgdx, camera, maps, tiles

For the life of me I cannot figure out why these lines keep appearing on my rendered tiled map. Every time I resize my libgdx window, the tiled map creates lines all across the screen.

I have adjusted camera viewport, camera projection, camera zoom, etc, and I cannot figure anything out.

```
import com.badlogic.gdx.Gdx;
import com.badlogic.gdx.Input;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.OrthographicCamera;
import com.badlogic.gdx.graphics.g2d.SpriteBatch;
import com.badlogic.gdx.maps.tiled.TiledMap;
import com.badlogic.gdx.maps.tiled.TmxMapLoader;
import com.badlogic.gdx.maps.tiled.renderers.OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.MathUtils;
import com.badlogic.gdx.math.Vector3;
import com.prevail.mmorpg.PrevailGame;
import com.prevail.mmorpg.gfx.player.Player;
import com.prevail.mmorpg.gfx.player.Player.Direction;
import com.prevail.mmorpg.net.ClientNetworkState;

import io.netty.buffer.ByteBuf;
import io.netty.buffer.Unpooled;

public class PlayingScreen extends GameScreen {

    public Player player = new Player();

    private OrthographicCamera camera;

    private TmxMapLoader mapLoader;
    private TiledMap map;
    private OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer renderer;
    private final int[] renderBackground = { 0, 1, 2 };
    private final int[] renderForeground = { 3, 4, 5 };

    private float cameraTime;

    public PlayingScreen(PrevailGame game) {
        super(game);
        this.camera = new OrthographicCamera(Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), Gdx.graphics.getHeight());

        Player.initializeAppearanceConstructors(game.getData());

        this.mapLoader = new TmxMapLoader();
        this.map = mapLoader.load("maps/Starter Map.tmx");
        this.renderer = new OrthogonalTiledMapRenderer(map);
        this.player.map = map;
    }

    @Override
    public void enterScreen() {
        this.game.writeRawMessage(Unpooled.buffer(1).writeByte(1));
        PrevailGame.CLIENT_STATE = ClientNetworkState.PLAYING;

        player.setAppearance("1", "2", null, "5");
        player.faceDirection(Direction.SOUTH);
    }

    @Override
    public void renderScreen(SpriteBatch batch, float delta) {
        batch.setTransformMatrix(this.camera.view);
        batch.setProjectionMatrix(this.camera.projection);

        OrthographicCamera camera = (OrthographicCamera) this.camera;
        if (camera.position.equals(player.getLocation())) {
            cameraTime = 0;
        } else {
            camera.position.lerp(player.getLocation(), MathUtils.clamp(cameraTime, 0.0f, 1.0f));
            camera.update();
        }
        renderer.setView(camera);
        renderer.render(renderBackground);
        player.render(batch, delta);
        renderer.render(renderForeground);

        if (Gdx.input.isKeyPressed(Input.Keys.SHIFT_LEFT)) {
            player.setRunning(true);
        } else {
            player.setRunning(false);
        }
        cameraTime += delta;
    }

    @Override
    public void resize(int width, int height) {
        super.resize(width, height);

        this.camera = new OrthographicCamera(width, height);
    }

    @Override
    public void leaveScreen() {

    }

    @Override
    public boolean scrolled(float amountX, float amountY) {
        OrthographicCamera camera = (OrthographicCamera) this.camera;

        float newValue = camera.zoom + (amountY / 100f);
        if (newValue < 0.15f) {
            newValue = 0.15f;
        } else if (newValue > 2f) {
            newValue = 2f;
        }
        camera.zoom = newValue;

        camera.update();
        return super.scrolled(amountX, amountY);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean touchDown(int screenX, int screenY, int pointer, int button) {
        Vector3 clickCoordinates = new Vector3(screenX, screenY, 0);
        Vector3 position = camera.unproject(clickCoordinates);

        int gx = (int) (position.x / (int) 32) * 32;
        int gy = (int) (position.y / (int) 32) * 32;

        ByteBuf walkRequestPacket = Unpooled.buffer(10);
        walkRequestPacket.writeShort(gx / 32);
        walkRequestPacket.writeShort(gy / 32);
        this.game.writePacket(10, walkRequestPacket);
        return super.touchDown(screenX, screenY, pointer, button);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean keyDown(int keyCode) {
        return super.keyDown(keyCode);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean keyUp(int keyCode) {
        return super.keyUp(keyCode);
    }

}
```

Without Resizing window: [image]

[image]

Comment: [Does this past Q&A help](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/q/108701/39518)?

Comment: No, I'm sorry it does not. It only helps when moving the character and not resizing the window :(